# What command do I use as an "and" function?

Tags: python

I want to imply a condition to the inputs I am using.
Example: if_button_b.was_displayed #and target number = 5 then
             display.show("win")
Basically, what I want to do is: #if button b is pressed on 5 in the counting then display win, if not display lose.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But this is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. You better should ask general programming questions at https://stackoverflow.com. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the word `and` between conditionals, e.g:

```
if button_a.is_pressed and button_b.is_pressed:
    print("both pressed")
elif button_a.is_pressed:
    print("a pressed")
elif button_b.is_pressed:
    print("b pressed")
```